# Do Crystaline solids convert to amorphous solids over time?

Tags: thermodynamics

Do crystalline substances(like quratz) become amorphous over time? I can't find anything on the web.
I feel they do as this increases entropy. Could someone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a clue towards an answer to this question, I think. There is a process that goes in the opposite direction of what you are asking about.

Glass blowers have to take precautions against the occurence of a process that is named '[devitrification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devitrification)'. Devitrification is when the substance that is being worked starts to crystallize.

As I understand it, once devitrification has started it cannot be reverted.

It would appear that in going to a crystalline state the amount of energy released is sufficient to drive the loss of entropy.

Conversely, that would lead one to expect that to go from crystalline to amorphous comes at an energy cost high enough such that the gain in entropy cannot drive it.

Comment: So basically the enthalpy of crystallization is much much greater than the gain in entropy, right?Thanks!

Comment: The enthalpy and the entropy  of crystallization (or any phase transition) are related via $$\Delta H = T \Delta S$$ where $T$ is the temperature of the phase transition. This means that in order to increase entropy by $\Delta S$ you need to have energy $\Delta H$. If you don't have that much energy you cannot gain that much entropy.

Answer (score 2):

Just because a change increases the entropy of the system does not imply that the system will necessarily undergo the change. Case at point: liquids have higher entropy than solids and gases have higher entropy than liquids. We cannot conclude that the equilibrium state of matter is gas. Entropy maximization works only under the strict condition that energy, as as well as volume and number of particles, are fixed. If there is not enough energy to gasify the system the equilibrium state will be some other phase or mixture of phases.

Comment: So basically, at most temperatures, the Gibbs fee ener is positive, right?

Comment: Yes, if a spontaneous  transition is not observed, the Gibbs free energy must be positive. I say "must" be positive, because  the fact that a spontaneous process is not observed might also be the result of slow kinetics.

Answer (score 0):

AIP Conference Proceedings 982, 108 (2008); doi: 10.1063/1.2897763

> Figure 5a shows the evolutions of the x-ray diffraction pattern of
> phase $\alpha$ during the annealing at 110°C and 117°C. The
> progressive disappearance of the Bragg peaks confirms the isothermal
> amorphization process.
>
> we showed...the direct transformations from crystal to glass of the
> different crystalline forms of trehalose upon...annealing.
>
> Upon annealing below $\mathrm{T_g}$, the crystalline form $\alpha$
> obtained by slow dehydration of $\mathrm{T_{\; 2H_2O}}$ vitrifies
> slowly but spontaneously, indicating that the phase $\alpha$ is in a
> very unusual superheating situation. This behavior suggests that the
> effective melting temperature ($\;\mathrm{T}^{eff}_m$) of the phase
> $\alpha$ is likely to be located far below the glass transition
> temperature (T )$_g$ of this compound.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!1